# How to exit gracefully-trouble socket error handling

Tags: python, sockets

Hi I am writing a script for user to input url.I am supposed to verify the url and let user know if the url is valid.If I purposefully type wrong url I am getting an error message of gaierror ,but I have put the error handling code here so that my program gets a message "can not connect" like a graceful exit.Seems like the code line "if sock is None:
-print 'could not open socket' is not executed in the program below.I am new in socket programming.I think I am doing something wrong.Could anyone please help me here.Thanks in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import sys


def hello(c):
  t=c
  port = 80
  slash=t.split("/")
  basename="/".join(slash[2:3])
  pathname="/"+"/".join(slash[3:])
  sock=None

  for res in socket.getaddrinfo(basename, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
     af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
     try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     except socket.error:
        sock= None
        continue
     try:
        sock.connect((basename, port))
     except socket.error:            
        sock= None
        continue

  if sock is None:
    print 'could not open socket'###I dont get this printed 
    sys.exit(0)   

  sock.send("HEAD %s HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" % pathname)
  l=sock.recv(12)
  return l
  sys.exit(1)
  sock.close()


``I call the hello function from here``
k= hello("https://mail.yah")`purposefully wrong to verify error handle
print k
newsplit=k.split()
print newsplit
insplit=eval(newsplit[1])
print insplit
if insplit==404:
 print "bad"
else:
 print "ok"
```

I get the error message below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/myserver/cgi-bin/domain.py", line 40, in <module>
 k= hello("https://mail.yah")
 "C:/myserver/cgi-bin/domain.py", line 13, in hello
 for res in socket.getaddrinfo(basename, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
 gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Hi Thomas,Thanks! it is not showing that error anymore.great trick! I just have a quick question:).When I have this wrong url entry in the function, then my system exits at sys.exit(0)- at this point I am getting the error the message below:Do you have any suggestion about getting out of this without traceback.Thanks for your help!                                                      //Error:Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/myserver cgi-bin    //domain.py", line 45, in <module> k= hello("mail.yah";) File   //"C:/myserver/cgi-bin/domain.py", line 33, in hello sys.exit(0) SystemExit:0

Answer (score 0):

You might want to wrap that `socket.getaddrinfo(basename, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`in a `try` / `except socket.gaierror` block, which should do the trick:

```
try:
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(basename, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
         # stuff
except socket.gaierror:
    print 'getaddrinfo failed!'
```

---

Indeed, it's in fact the `socket.getaddrinfo(basename, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` that's causing the error!

Comment: Thanks! it is not showing that error anymore.great trick! I just have a quick question:).When I have this wrong url entry in the function, then my system exits at sys.exit(0)- at this point am I supposed to get the message below: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/myserver/cgi-bin/domain.py", line 45, in <module> k= hello("mail.yah";) File "C:/myserver/cgi-bin/domain.py", line 33, in hello sys.exit(0) SystemExit:0

Comment: @RobinClarke That's strange that you are shown the traceback, but `sys.exit()` does raise a `SystemExit`exception, so it's not that surprising. You probably have error logging in place?